# Вывод данных из массива json в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, bootstrap

Пытаюсь подгрузить данные из json с помощью jquery, и в общем не получается 
вот код

html

```
   <a id="1" href="" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img src="img/photo/3-2.png"/>
    </a>
```

modal.js

```
var data=[
    {
            "dancer_name": "Lombardia",
            "city": "lom",
            "dance": "asasa",
            "age": 44,
            "description": "Лабудабудабудада",
            "id": "1"
        }
];

(function($) {
    var infoModal = $('#myModal');
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          url: 'modal.js?id='+$(this).data('id'),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){ 
            htmlData = '<ul><li>name: '+data.dancer_name+'</li><li>city: '+data.city+'</li></ul>';
            infoModal.find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);
            modal.modal('show');
          }
        });

        return true;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

ошибка

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит что такого файла нет.

Если используется какой-нибудь роутинг, возвращающий ответ в зависимости от параметра `id`, от тут тоже ошибка, так как при составлении `url` идет попытка взять `$(this).data('id')` и, так как предполагается, что значение должно браться из разметки

```
<a id="1" href="" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

видно что в данной разметке нет атрибута `data-id` поэтому возвращенное значение будет всегда *undefined*, если не будет установлено вручную в скрипте.

Таким образом нужно либо изменить разметку добавив атрибут `data-id`

```
<a id="1" data-id="1" href="" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Либо в скрипте брать атрибут/свойство `id`

```
url: 'modal.js?id='+$(this).attr('id'),
```

или

```
url: 'modal.js?id='+this.id,
```